# Detecting International Characters In Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's a regular expression to detect product pages on amazon. It works for pages in standard english but not for url's with international characters. So URL2 is not detected. How do I get around this? Thanks.

```
var URL1 = "www.amazon.com/Big-Short-Inside-Doomsday-Machine/dp/0393338827/";
var URL2 = "www.amazon.fr/Larm%C3%A9e-furieuse-Fred-Vargas/dp/2878583760/";

var regex1 = RegExp("http://www.amazon.(com|co.uk|de|ca|it|fr|cn|co.jp)/([\\w-]+/)?(dp|gp/product)/(\\w+/)?(\\w{10})");
m = URL1.match(regex1);
```

Comment: Um...I'm not seeing any non-7-bit-ASCII characters in `URL2`... **Edit: Never mind**, something weird going on with SO's markdown parser.

Comment: For some reason the URL would be changed to stackflow everytime I posted, you should see it now.

Comment: @user: Oddly, no. I can see it in the edit window, but it's not coming across outside the edit window. Very, very strange.

Comment: Yeah, there's something wrong with stack, I get see it properly every time I edit, but the parser changes the URL when I save.

Comment: That is **very** weird. I tried changing to to a `pre` tag. No luck.

Comment: Recommend you post something to http://meta.stackoverflow.com about it.

Comment: Hi, T.J. Crowder, I'm moving the URL's outside the code area until the parsers fixed.

Comment: Taking off the http seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` doesn't match `\w`, so `Larm%C3%A9e-furieuse-Fred-Vargas` doesn't match `[\w-]+`. Why not just use `[^/]+`?

PS — "`.`" matches any character, so you should use pattern `\.`, which would appear as `\\.` in the literal.

```
RegExp("http://www\\.amazon\\.(ca|cn|co\\.(jp|uk)|com|de|fr|it)/([^/]+/)?(dp|gp/product)/(\\w+/)?(\\w{10})");
```